# Clean dual boot machine

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows, mint

What would be the best way to completely remove windows 10 and ubuntu from a machine with a dual boot? Remove two OSs, but keep everything set up (bios, etc) for easy clean install of linux (Mint or Ubuntu).

I'm interested in a case when there's no need to keep any files from both systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just reinstall Linux (Mint or Ubuntu), if that is the OS you want to have.

During the installation, it will ask you how you want to partition your hard drive. Select '**Erase disk and install Ubuntu**'. That should take care of what you want. (The following image won't  show your exact options, but should look close enough).

[image]

The only thing I can think of that you might have trouble with is having Ubuntu registered as an UEFI boot option. But if you already had a dual-boot system working, then this might not be an issue at all.

Comment: is there a way to do this without USB drive with Linux?

Comment: You could use gparted to remove the Windows partitions, enlarge the Linux ones and then fix your boot setup with Boot-Repair. This might take a lot longer than a reinstall, but it should be possible.

Comment: I guess that'll work for me